# Watin Exception

Tags: c#, watin

I'm trying to fill up a textfield using watin. The problem is:

```
   browser.TextField(Find.ByName("fieldname")).TypeText("Test");
```

I keep getting an exception. When I try to loop through textfield elements using the following code:

```
  browser.TextFields.Count
```

The same core.ElementFactory exception occurs. Any ideas what's wrong? Thanks!

This is the inner exception:

```
  {"Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.SHDocVw, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db7cfd3acb5ad44e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Interop.SHDocVw, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db7cfd3acb5ad44e"}
```

EDIT:

The problem was even though I linked Interop.SHDocVw.dll into the project, for some reason it wasn't in projects directory so I copied it manually and now it's working. Thanks!

Comment: Try adding a tag to get more views